# using DXL : open source module of a link in edit mode

Tags: ibm-doors

Here is my script taken from internet, it is the common way to open source module of link before beeing able to explore source objects of links :

```
LinkRef lr;
for lr in o<-(fullName (current Project) "/_conf/" VV_NOUVELLE_EXL_REPOND_A_EXS) do 
                { 
                    ModuleVersion mvSource = sourceVersion lr 
                    Module modSrc = data mvSource 
                    
                    if (null modSrc)
                    {                      
                        modSrc = load(mvSource, false)
                        // then openin the corresponding module in edit mode (I hope there is a more simple way to do this) :
                        modSrc = edit(fullName(modSrc), false)
```

[...]

The problem I have is that I need to open the module in edit mode, this is why I add :
modSrc = edit(fullName(modSrc), false)

without it I can't modify the object of the source link.
Be doing this I have now a baseline (current) and a module that is open, right ?
so I need to close the current baseline opened using load ? (I did this after opening the module in edit mode but then I can't modify anymore the source object)
or better, can I directly open the module without doing the load before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly open source module in edit mode with following code and edit the source object.

```
LinkRef lref
string s
Object obj
for lref in obj<-"*"do
 {
     s=fullName(source(lref))
     Module mod = edit(s,false)
     //Do your operations here
 }
```